# typedef'ing function *signature* (not a pointer to), so that it can be reused?

Tags: c++, syntax, function-pointers, typedef

**EDIT: MOTIVATION**

Suppose I define a Handler class as

```
class Handler {
public:
  class Message { /*...*/ };
  typedef int (*Callback)(Message *msg);
  void registerCallback(int msgclass, Callback f);
};
```

A client can do

```
int f1(Handler::Message *msg)
{ /* handle message */ }

int f2(Handler::Message *msg)
{ /* handle message */ }

int main(){
  Handler h;
  h.registerCallback(1, f1);
  h.registerCallback(2, f2);
  // ....
}
```

The compiler will indeed check that `f1` and `f2` are appropriate as parameters to `registerCallback`, however, it's up to the client to define `f1` and `f2` correctly. Since I've allready `typedef`ed `Callback`, I'd like the client to be able to use it instead.

**END EDIT**

I'd like to do something like this:

```
typedef int arithmetic(int i, int j);

arithmetic sum
{
 return i+j;
}

arithmetic max
{
  return (i>j)? i:j;
}
// etc.
```

However, both

```
arithmetic sum
arithmetic sum()
```

don't compile, and also this

```
arithmetic sum(int i, int j)
```

which gives compiler error of

> func.cpp:4: error: ‘sum’ declared as
>   function returning a function

The reason I want this is that I want to have a `Handler` class which would provide a `typedef` for a callback function it accepts, **including the parameter list**.

Comment: I don't see how you want to pass the parameters to your arithmetic. What is i and j in your example.

Comment: Can you use Boost, or facilities from C++0x?

Comment: @mkaes: right, it'a typo, corrected.

Comment: @luke: yes to both, as this is my "spare time" little project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you did not typedef a signature. A signature is everything that identifies a single function. It contains the namespace/class of the function and so on.

What you typedef'ed is the type of a function. Like when you `typedef int inttype` which typedefs the type of an `int`, you typedef'ed the type of a function.

You can use the typedef-name to declare functions only.

```
arithmetic max; // valid
```

But it cannot be used to define functions. For defining functions, you need to provide a parameter list literally and manually. Reasons include giving names for parameters (and possibly other, more technical reasons. C++0x introduces `arithmetic max {};` which will get a specific initialization meaning).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is more clear now. Actually, my question boils down to providing kind of "default" parameter names. It seems a nice feature to have (see added "MOTIVATION" in the OP). Could you explain the C++0x addition you mention - how is it used?

Comment: @davka `T t{}` value initializes `t`. So for example `int a{};` value initializes `a` to zero. It's the uniform initialization proposal that has been accepted into C++0x.

Comment: thanks, so e.g. I can write `arithmetic max { min };` which would define `max` as variable pointing to the function `min`? BTW, I thought that it was the array and struct initialization extended, so it should be `arithmetic max = {min};`, is it?

Comment: @davka `arithmetic` is a function type. If you want to define a function pointer, you need to say `arithmetic *max{ min };`. The point is, syntactically, `type name{}` is a variable declaration with an initializer, not a function definition.

Comment: @davka if you want to further ask about this C++0x feature, then best make up a new question.

Answer (score 13):

I'll give you a classic C answer, without resorting to the newfangled C++0x toys. Let's start by defining a function prototype:

```
typedef int TWO_ARG_FUNC(int x, int y);
```

You can use this prototype when receiving a function pointer, e.g.:

```
void blah(TWO_ARG_FUNC* funcPtr);
```

... or when forward-declaring a function:

```
TWO_ARG_FUNC max;
```

... but you **cannot** implement a function by just writing the prototype, e.g.:

```
TWO_ARG_FUNC max
{
   ... // bzzt, error!
}
```

However, not all is lost. You can enforce the function to remain true to a prototype by first forward-declaring it:

```
TWO_ARG_FUNC max;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to resort to C macros:

```
#define DEFINE_TWO_ARG_FUNC(funcName) int funcName(int a, int b)

DEFINE_TWO_ARG_FUNC(max)
{
}
```

and you can even use the macro to declare a function prototype, in case you later want to declare a pointer to such a function:

```
typedef DEFINE_TWO_ARG_FUNC(TWO_ARG_FUNC);
```

Comment: One of the best uses of macros that I've seen, thanks! And the last line with typedef is really cool :)

Comment: I don't believe that `int max(a, b) { }` is semantically valid. The C spec says about function definitions "If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in the declaration list shall have at least one declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers from the identifier list, and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared.". (identifier list being "a, b", and the declaration list being "int a, b;" in the following: `int max(a, b) int a, b; { ... }`).

Comment: Johannes, you were right, though not in the sense that I should use old-style C declaration, but in the sense that my argument types defaulted to int without me realizing it. That's why I should compile with warnings, especially when writing smartass stackoverflow answers :-) Fixing my answer accordingly.

Comment: What a great answer! I was looking for a solution in C, found this question, and your answer was just the kind of idea I had on my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about your post I will give it a shot about what you want to archive.
You could try using boost or C++0x lambda. I will go with boost.

```
typedef boost::function<int(int,int)> arithmetic;
arithmetic sum = (boost::lambda::_1 + boost::lambda::_2);
arithmetic max = boost::lambda::if_then_else_return(boost::lambda::_1 > boost::lambda::_2,
    boost::lambda::_1, boost::lambda::_2);

int j = sum(3,3); // j ist 6
int k = max(4,2); // k is 4
```

So maybe this is what you want to archive.

It is also possible with a full blown function.
Here you go.

```
int FullBodyFunction(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}
arithmetic sum2 = boost::bind(&FullBodyFunction, _1, _2);
```

This will do the same as sum1. You are free to use the whole boost bind stuff. E.g. bind to method of a object or what ever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Is it useful mainly for short ad-hoc fucntions? Would it be reasonable to write a "real" function with this technique?

Comment: What is a real function? You can of course bind to function. You do not have to use lambda.

Comment: by "real" I mean a function not as simple as max, a function with a "full body" so to speak

Answer (score 2):

Since, as you say, you can use C++0x, you might choose to do something like this by typedef'ing a `function`:

**edit**, added in your concept of a handler class containing a callback typedef:

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a>=b) ? a : b;
}

class Handler
{
    public:

        //typedef int (*Callback)(int, int);
        typedef std::function<int (int, int)> Callback;

        void add(Callback func) { functions_.push_back(func); }

    private:

        std::list<Callback> functions_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Handler handler;

    handler.add([](int a, int b) -> int { return (a>=b) ? a : b; });
    handler.add(max);

    return 0;
}
```

This isn't the exact syntax you're looking for, but as others have pointed out, it isn't possible to use typedef for a function signature directly.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. Still, does not allow me to be as user-friendly as I'd like to. I guess the only was is to resort to old good (or bad) C macros...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't find solution with exact syntax you are looking for, but something like this works:

```
#include <cassert>

#define  arithmetic (int i, int j) -> int

#define declare(Func, Name) auto Name Func

#define as_

auto sum as_ arithmetic
{
  return i + j;
};

declare(arithmetic, max)
{
  return (i>j) ? i : j;
};

int main()
{
  assert(sum(2, 4) == 6);
  assert(max(2, 4) == 4);

  return 0;
}
```