# Can I use a function typedef in function definitions?

Tags: c++, c, function, typedef

I've defined:

```
typedef int FunkyFunc(int x);
```

Now, I would like to be able to use this typedef in the definition of functions of type `FunkyFunc`, e.g.

```
FunkyFunc f {
    return 2*x;
}
```

or

```
FunkyFunc f(int x) {
    return 2*x;
}
```

or

```
FunkyFunc f(x) {
    return 2*x;
}
```

can I do something similar to any of the above? None of them seems to compile.

Comment: May function pointers can help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195269/typedefing-function-signature-not-a-pointer-to-so-that-it-can-be-reused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can use the typedef to *declare* a function:

```
FunkyFunc f;
```

but a function definition must be written with a function-style declarator.

<sub>Note: This is certainly the case in C++, and I'm fairly sure C is the same in this regard; but it would be better if you chose a single language to ask about, since there can be significant differences between C and C++ even where you might imagine they'd be the same.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

This is *ill-formed* in *C++* from the draft standard section `8.3.5` *Functions* paragraph *10* says:

> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function (8.4).
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> F fv; // OK: equivalent to void fv();
> F fv { } // ill-formed
> void fv() { } // OK: definition of fv
> ```
>
> —end example ][...]

We can see in *C* this is also specifically forbidden from the C99 draft standard section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* says:

> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall
>   have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition.<sup>141)</sup>

and footnote `141` says:

> The intent is that the type category in a function definition cannot be inherited from a typedef:

and has the following example:

```
typedef int F(void); // type F is ‘‘function with no parameters
                     // returning int’’
F f, g; // fand g both have type compatible with F
F f { /* ... */ } // WRONG: syntax/constraint error
[...]
```

*C11* says the same things except the footnote is `162`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `#define`s to simulate what the C language does not allow (as pointed out by [*Mike Seymour*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20840889/694576)):

```
#define MYFUNKYFUNC(f) int f(int x)

MYFUNKYFUNC(f1)
{
  return x;
}

MYFUNKYFUNC(f2)
{
  return 2*x;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x1 = f1(2); /* Assigns 2 to x1. */
  int x2 = f2(2); /* Assigns 4 to x2. */

  return 0;
}
```

Whether your fellow coders will like you for doing so is a different story though.

Comment: It is an interesting alternative although I would not want to maintain it.

Answer (score -1):

Just write `int f(int x) { return 2*x; }`.

If you want to pass a "FunkyFunc" as a parameter to another function, for example

`void do_something(FunkyFunc *func) { ... }`

Then you can simply write

`do_something(&f);`

Answer (score -1):

What you have written will not work the way you want.  Typedef is an alias to another type.  Imagine that your typedef is not much more than a #define.  Then see what the code would look like.

```
int FunkyFunc(int x) f {
return 2*x;
}
```

This syntax will not compile.

Comment: This is not the reason why it does not work. It's not about syntax; `typedef`s are not even remotely related to preprocessor macros. If this form wasn't specifically forbidden, it would absolutely make sense for it to compile.