# How to use typedef for extern function in C?

Tags: c, typedef, c11

I have two modules written in C11 in my project: 'test1.c' and 'test2.c'.
Module 'test1.c':

```
int FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName(char* data)
{
    // do something
}
```

Module 'test2.c':

```
extern int FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName(char* data);

int main(void)
{
    char data[ DATA_LEN + 1 ] = { "test_data" };
    FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName(data);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use short name for function 'FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName' in module 'test2.c' without modification of module 'test1.c'. F.e., something like this:

```
FuncWithShortName(data);
```

I try to do:

```
extern int FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName(char* data);
typedef int FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName(char* data);
FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName FuncWithShortName;

int main(void)
{
    char data[ DATA_LEN + 1 ] = { "test_data" };
    FuncWithShortName(data);
    return 0;
}
```

But compiler gave an error:
"Definition of function FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGNamerequires parentheses."
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: That's not what `typedef` does. If used correctly it creates an alias of a *type*. It can't be used to shorten arbitrary symbols.

Comment: You should instead focus on solving your biggest problem - why is the function which such a long name anyway?

Comment: You can do `#define shortname FunctionWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName`. This will expand `shortname` to the long name.

Comment: I'm looking to this example. Here 'typedef' is used for functions and I want to find trick like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840822/can-i-use-a-function-typedef-in-function-definitions

Comment: Module 'test2.c' was written by my colleague. I can't modify it because it's not mine.

Comment: You read that in the completely wrong context. The question you read is still about defining *type* aliases, not about "shortening" symbols.

Comment: C/C++ does not support alias or rename of symbols. Compilers and related tools generally do. [objcopy --redefine-sym](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) is one way.

Comment: Some programmer dude, thank you for clear understanding!

Comment: Paul, thank you, it works fine

Comment: @АннексийЖимолостный Using a macro is kind of a dirty solution though, since macros sit in the global namespace. The posted answer with a function pointer is better.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` creates a type alias, not a function alias or anything else.

You could get a sort of function alias by defining a file-local pointer to function:

```
static int (*const FuncWithShortName)(char*) =
    FuncWithVeryLONGLONGLONGLONGName;
```